# Youtube video iframe not load

Tags: iframe, youtube

I put video in iframe on my site, and not work, I have error

```
Failed to load https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id: Redirect from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' to 'about:blank' has been blocked by CORS policy: Redirect location 'about:blank' has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.
```

My youtube code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HiixPZ0xkk0" frameborder="0" style="height: 0px;"></iframe></div>
```

Any idea?

EDIT:

Full errors
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download the video and use that as your source too.

Comment: What do copyright say about it? I do not think this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find solution here: http://centrumps.pl/iframe-problem-w-prestashop-1-7-z-youtube/

must remove www from address